# Deploy Scripts to AWS-Greengrass without AWS-Lambda

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, aws, aws-greengrass

Is it possible to deploy to Greengrass from another source besides Lambda?

Could I possibly connect to AWS-Greengrass with a client like MQTT.fx and deploy scripts to it?

I have tried several times connecting to Greengrass with MQTT.fx, but replacing my AWS IoT endpoint with my local server address, to no avail. I usually receive an "MQTTException" error. I am connecting with the appropriate SSL/TLS Settings for connection to the AWS IoT endpoint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since no answer in all this time, here is one.
We have connected Greengrass to NODE-RED.

https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2019/06/iot-control-system-at-edge-mimic-mqtt.html

The NODE-RED subscriber is just another device in your Greengrass group that
you need to allow to subscribe.

Update: copy/pasted the relevant section as requested

When the actuator (eg. cooling system) in the control system is off, the sensor
temperature heats, and when it is on, then it cools. We implemented the control
system logic in a Node-RED flow, rather than in a Lambda function.

[image]

It turns the actuator on if the temperature exceeds a high threshold, and turns it
off if the temperature is cool enough. The connectivity to the core broker is setup
as a subscriber to the shadow updates as shown below on the right:

[image]

Comment: Please put the details in the actual answer, link only answers will become useless as soon as the link breaks.